# Shortest Path Implementation Issue

Tags: c++, graph

I am implementing the [Shortest Path Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) in C++. Basically the user enters a `SourceVertex` and the function `FindShortestPath(int SourceVertex)` finds and prints the shortest paths from the `SourceVertex` to all the remaining vertices.

```
void Graph::FindShortestPath(int SourceVertex)
{
    cout<<"The shortest paths from "<<SourceVertex<<" are"<<endl;
    //initialize the ShortestPathArray
    for(int a=0;a<NumberOfVertices;a++)
        ShortestPathArray[a]=numeric_limits<int>::max();
    ShortestPathArray[SourceVertex]=0;

    for(int a=0;a<NumberOfVertices;a++)
    {
        if(WeightMatrix[SourceVertex][a]!=0)
            ShortestPathArray[a]=WeightMatrix[SourceVertex][a];

    }
    cout<<"Direct Edges Length"<<endl;
    for(int a=0;a<NumberOfVertices;a++)
    {
        cout<<SourceVertex<<"->"<<a<<"="<<ShortestPathArray[a]<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"Shortest Path after updating"<<endl;

    for(int a=0;a<NumberOfVertices;a++)
        for(int b=0;b<NumberOfVertices;b++)

            if(WeightMatrix[a][b]!=0)//edge exists
            {   if(ShortestPathArray[b]>(ShortestPathArray[a]+WeightMatrix[a][b]))
            {
                ShortestPathArray[b]= ShortestPathArray[a]+WeightMatrix[a][b];}}   

    for(int a=0;a<NumberOfVertices;a++)
    cout<<SourceVertex<<"->"<<a<<"="<<ShortestPathArray[a]<<endl;}
```

I get the following output

```
The shortest paths from 4 are
Direct Edges Length
4->0=2147483647
4->1=6
4->2=10
4->3=4
4->4=0
Shortest Path after updating
4->0=2147483647
4->1=-2147483645
4->2=-2147483646
4->3=-2147483644
4->4=-2147483647
```

The first set that is printed is correct. Something in wrong in the updating part. I can't seem to figure that out.

**EDIT-1**

```
int main(){

    Graph g(5);
    g.AddEdge(0,4,2);
    g.AddEdge(0,2,3);
    g.AddEdge(0,1,5);
    g.AddEdge(1,3,6);
    g.AddEdge(1,2,2);
    g.AddEdge(4,3,4);
    g.AddEdge(4,1,6);
    g.AddEdge(4,2,10);
    g.AddEdge(2,1,1);
    g.AddEdge(2,3,2);
    g.FindShortestPath(4);

    return 0;

}
```

Following is my input code

Comment: Please show thw data on which the undesired behaviour occurs.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(WeightMatrix[a][b]!=0)//edge exists
{   
    if(ShortestPathArray[b]>(ShortestPathArray[a]+WeightMatrix[a][b]))
    {
        ShortestPathArray[b]= ShortestPathArray[a]+WeightMatrix[a][b];
    }
}
```

here for e.g a=0 value of ShortestPathArray[a]=2147483647; i.e the max range, and in this value you are adding more value so it is going out of range.
try with some smaller value than the max limit.

Comment: It helped. When I was adding more values to the max value, it was getting wrapped to a negative value and hence adding an abs helped.

Comment: yes, if you add more value to max value, it will give some -ve value. Good to know that problem is solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem for me.

Changing

```
if(WeightMatrix[a][b]!=0)//edge exists
            {   if(ShortestPathArray[b]>(ShortestPathArray[a]+WeightMatrix[a][b]))
            {
                ShortestPathArray[b]= ShortestPathArray[a]+WeightMatrix[a][b];}}
```

to

```
if(WeightMatrix[a][b]!=0)//edge exists
            {   if(ShortestPathArray[b]>abs(ShortestPathArray[a]+WeightMatrix[a][b]))
            {
                ShortestPathArray[b]= ShortestPathArray[a]+WeightMatrix[a][b];}}
```

Adding the **abs** solved the problem. Apparently some values of `ShortestPathArray` were negative.If initially some value was `numeric_limits<int>::max()` and I was adding something to it,the final result wrapped around to a negative value. Hence adding the abs() function helped.

Comment: `ShortestPathArray[b]= ShortestPathArray[a]+WeightMatrix[a][b];` I think in this line also you should use `abs`.If it is working fine then no problem.